# How to force Universal Application to release memory?

Tags: c#, xaml, memory-management, win-universal-app, windows-10

Created a simple app that leaks memory:

**View**

```
<Page
   ...
    x:Class="App3.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Width="300" Height="200" 
            Source="/Assets/BBlHOiv.jpg"></Image>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">Navigate</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();            
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
```

Every time the button is clicked, the code navigates to the same page which has an image on it ~400KB.  If I continue to click the button at a quick pace, the memory rises each click, or ever few clicks.  The memory is not reclaimed, or at least not in a timely manner.  In a real app, with more complex pages and more complex navigation (including circular navigation) this can be become a big problem.  Question is, how to force the app to release the memory?  Ideally, once a page is no longer needed/shown.

I've tried the following things with no luck.

**#1 Clearing the frame's navigation stack**

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        this.Frame.BackStack.Clear();
    }
```

**#2 When using MVVM, setting the DataContext to null (when datacontext is set in the XAML markup)**

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        this.DataContext = null;
        this.Frame.BackStack.Clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector in .Net does it at it's own pace and not necessarily when things are closed.  I don't recommend doing this, but you can manually call `GC.Collect();`.  I would track down the source of the "leak".

More information on the garbage collection process:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

If the number and size of the images isn't too large, the images could be loaded as static resources in the App object and the pages could refer to these (StaticResource). This way they would only be loaded once at startup and they should appear very quickly.

If this would require too much memory an alternative would be to load the image in code when the page is opened, keep a reference to the image, and when the page closes the image could be disposed of explicitly. This will be slower but might save memory. Again, as mentioned, there is no guarantee that the memory will be released immediately upon calling Dispose.